# SQL query using string concatenation

Tags: php, sql

I am new to php and I have a table "abc" where I have columns: id, name and age.
I want to do the following:

Only if a name is entered in the input field, corresponding data (id and age) should be shown using string concatenation to build SQL query.

This is for search functionality

What should be the SQL query for this question?

```
// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($SERVER_NAME, $USER_NAME, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE_NAME);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    

        $sql = " SELECT name, CONCAT(id,'.',age) FROM personene WHERE name = 'VALUE_FROM INPUT_NAME'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $error = mysqli_error($conn);

        // Store results
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php if(!empty($error))
    echo "<p style='color:red'>$error</p>";
?>
<p>Please enter the name:</p>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="GET">
<input type="input" name="name" value="" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="sendbtn" value="Send" />
</form>
<?php
    if(!empty($data)) {
        echo "<h1>Persons:</h1><table border='1'><tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Age</th></tr>";
        foreach($data as $row) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["age"]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else
        echo "No data available";

        echo '(Query: '.$sql.')';      
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: SELECT name, CONCAT(id,'.',age) FROM abc

Comment: perhaps `select name, if( id is not null and age is not null, concat(id,'-',age),'') from abc`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius  the query doesn't seem to show the id, age when the name is entered in the Input field (HTML)

Comment: @maniksidana the query doesn't seem to show the id, age when the name is entered in the Input field (HTML)

Comment: what input field? please add your code

Comment: SELECT name, CONCAT(id,'.',age) FROM abc WHERE name = 'VALUE_FROM INPUT_FIELD'

Comment: the last edit fundamentally changed the nature of the question but the question remains unclear as you posted no code or html to support the question

Comment: I have added the code @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: @maniksidana I have added my code, could u let me know what wrong am I doing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For the SQL query to find records related with name, you have to use this query,

```
select concat('id', '-', 'age') as user_data from abc where name = $REQUEST['search_name'];
```

OR you can use **LIKE**([check here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)) condition to get the records from the table.

```
select concat('id', '-', 'age') as user_data from abc where name like 
$REQUEST['search_name'];
```

Here is an update for your code,

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($SERVER_NAME, $USER_NAME, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE_NAME);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// echo "Connected successfully";

$data = [];
$sql = "Please submit the form.";

if(isset($_GET['sendbtn']) ) {
  $sql = " SELECT id, name, age FROM personene WHERE name = '". $_GET['name'] ."'";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $error = mysqli_error($conn);

  // Store results
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php 
    if(!empty($error))
       echo "<p style='color:red'>$error</p>";
    ?>
    <p>Please enter the name:</p>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="GET">
      <input type="input" name="name" value="" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" name="sendbtn" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <?php
      if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
        echo "<h1>Persons:</h1><table border='1'><tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Age</th></tr>";
        foreach($data as $row) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["age"]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "No data available";
    }
    echo '(Query: '.$sql.')';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey!  this works. But how to do the same using concatenation? Because I am figuring out SQL injections in my own code (as this is a part of my learning process in school).

Comment: @EverydayDeveloper Glad, it helped you. For concatenation use ```select concat('id', '-', 'age') as user_data from abc where name = $REQUEST['search_name'];```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you want to `concatenate` fields in the SQL query when clearly in the html these fields are displayed in their own columns. The code you have is wide open to [SQL Injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) so you need to consider using a `prepared statement` to handle the user supplied input safely.

```
<?php
    $data=[];
    
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && !empty( $_GET['name'] ) ){
    
        $SERVER_NAME='';
        $USER_NAME='';
        $PASSWORD='';
        $DATABASE_NAME='';
        
        
        
        mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
        $conn=new mysqli( $SERVER_NAME, $USER_NAME, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE_NAME );
        
        try{
        
            $sql = 'select `name`, `id`, `age` from `personene` where `name` = ?';
            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['name'] );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result( $name, $id, $age);
            
            while( $stmt->fetch() )$data[]=[
                'name'  =>  $name,
                'id'    =>  $id,
                'age'   =>  $age
            ];
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
            
        }catch( mysqli_sql_exception $e ){
            exit( $e->getMessage() );
        }

    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fetch user details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <p>Please enter the name:</p>
        
        <form method='GET'>
            <input type='input' name='name' />
            <br/>
            <input type='submit' name='sendbtn' value='Send' />
        </form>
        
        
        <?php
            if( !empty( $data ) ) {
                echo "
                <h1>Persons:</h1>
                <table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                    </tr>";
                    
                foreach( $data as $row ) {
                    echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>{$row["id"]}</td>
                        <td>{$row["name"]}</td>
                        <td>{$row["age"]}</td>
                    </tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            } else {
                echo "No data available";
            }
        ?>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, I was given a task to figure out if SQL injection works in my code or not. 
But the query for that has to be written using "concatenation" only

Comment: I think that you perhaps misinterpreted the `concatenation` aspect of that challenge as I do not believe it was the use of `concat` that was the intention - more `where name=$var` type of thing. If you query takes user input ( ie: `$_GET['name']` ) and uses that in the sql query in place of `VALUE_FROM INPUT_NAME` then your code was vulnerable